# Javascript: Build String Query using backtick(`) but always added a new line

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-athena

Below code dynamically create string which is an athena query to run.
It always adding an unnecessary new line in the las string line.
I did this below way

```
arr = ["ee/User:1", "ww/User:2", ..., "ww/User:n"]
let len = arr.length;
columns = []
qq = "create external table users(";
for (let i = 0; i <= len - 1; i++) {

  let pp = arr[i].toLowerCase();
  //console.log(pp);
  pp = pp.replace("/", "_")
  pp = pp.replace(":", "_")
  pp = "`" + pp + "` String,"
  console.log(pp) // here also comming new line 
  colnames.push(pp)
}

let k = colnames.join("\n")
qq = qq + k;
console.log(qq)
```

It build the wrong query like below

```
  create external table users( `ee_user_1` String, 
                               `ww_user_2` String,
                               ....
                               `ww_user_n
                                `String,)
```

in last item do not know why new line comming unnecessary

Comment: may I know why negetive ?

Comment: I did not downvote, but you should provide a code example that we can run, not a rough approximation of one. Your code isn't even coherent because you have `columns` in one place and `colnames` in another, an undeclared `len` variable, etc. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is `len`? The normal way to write that is `i < len`.

Comment: I don't see any way this code could be adding a newline before `String`.

Comment: Does your input array, `arr`, have a newline at the end of the last string?

Comment: The newline must be in the last element of `arr`. How are you creating `arr`?

Comment: yes its adding one new line let me post colud watch logs picture here

Comment: no arr has no new line at all

Comment: added the snapshot how it come only for last item it come

Comment: It's very difficult to help you with a broken code sample. This is most likely why you are getting downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just the way you are logging the data - `console.log` will write its message with a new line `\n` at the end.

Change your final line from `console.log(qq)` to `console.log(qq + '***')`, and you will see the `***` is on the same line as the value of `qq`.

Comment: Thanks Lee I got to know blacktick in some os like AMI took in a different format(crazy things) while executing the code. I need to make String.formCode(96) it works then